# How can I unbind C-mouse-down-1 in emacs

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I am using   GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)
 of 2010-05-08 on G41R2F1

I find that I inadvertently get C-mouse-down-1 events, which pop up the buffer menu (laptop touch pad, that otherwise performs perfectly in respect of touch sensitivity).

I found out this is the cause by asking "where is mouse-buffer-menu" and emacs told me:

mouse-buffer-menu is on

I haven't been able to find a way to tell global-unset-key to unset this:

(global-unset-key "\C-mouse-down-1")   ; from googling

(global-unset-key "C-mouse-down-1")    ; logical guess

both throw errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no C-mouse-down-* events: did you mean C-mouse-1?

Try: (global-unset-key [C-mouse-1]) - works for me on Emacs 23.3 running on OSX.

Comment: Wow.   The actual event, which somehow I managed not to paste into my question, that emacs gave me, was  "C-down-mouse-1".   I somehow transposed the words in my head in typing the unset-key parameter.  Doh!  Be that as it may, thanks for the answer I needed, which was "use the correct sequence name, and (most importantly) use square brackets to quote it"   Thanks!

Comment: 99% of the time you can use what `C-h k` gives as the binding verbatim.  In this case it gives <C-down-mouse-1>, so you would do `(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-down-mouse-1>"))`.